# Shiny app does not work on Microsoft edge browser

Tags: server, shiny, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

we have developed a shiny dashboard. It is a combination of flexdasboard and shiny app. The dashboard was implemented on shiny server (free version, see below for more details).

The dashboard works fine on chrome, firefox, edge and internet explorer when accessing it through 'servername:3838/dashboard'.

However, when we try to access the dashboard through 'https://dashboard.company.com:3838/dashboard' it works on chrome, firefox and internet explorer but not on edge.

Any ideas where the problem could be?

Below are some details on the system we use.

Thanks

Thomas

Redhat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2(Maipo)

Shiny Server v1.4..4.801" "Node.js v0.10.46"

R Version 3.2.2

Shiny Package Version 1.0.5

Comment: What errors are you getting on edge? Without details about the error or the code there is no way we can help you with an aswer

Comment: Thanks. There is no error message on the screen. The dashboard is simply not displayed. White screen. Where can I find logs or messages?

Comment: See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003717168-Shiny-Server-Error-Logs, you'll want the application specific logs `/var/log/shiny-server/*.log`

Comment: Thanks for the valuble comments. We could narrow down the problem. It does in fact not work on a Microsoft Surface Hub. The error is about websockets. 'incorrect HTTP response. Status Code 400, bad request. Any ideas about how to fix this? Thanks. Thomas

Comment: @Thomas Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I'm interested too about update(s), it seems I have a similar problem

Comment: Me too. Nothing reporting in server logs. Just a 400 status code in Edge. V frustrating.

Comment: Hi, RStudio dev here. Please use this discourse thread if you're seeing this problem, we're actually paying attention over there! Thanks! https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-apps-fail-in-microsoft-edge-with-status-400/8292